# How to use ASPX page into MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As per requirement, i need to use existing/provided ASCX user controls into MVC application.
As understnad, to use these controls, I have to create ASPX traditional page into MVC and then use these user controls inside the ASPX page.

I can add webform into MVC application.

How can i incorporate URL for added webform ?? as it will be appear different url into the browser then other pages of MVC

PLease also suggest me if i have to take any other thing to incorporate traditional ASPX into MVC application.?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/391289/Implementing-ASP-NET-MVC-Views-in-three-different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually an ASP.NET project can host Web Forms, MVC and Web API. It's just about adding the right references to the whole project. Thus, you can create traditional `.aspx` pages in your project.

About "difference in URLs" when using Web Forms or MVC, this isn't longer true. Since ASP.NET 4.0, [Web Forms also supports URL Routing (follow this link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.ASPX).

Answer (score 2):

I use Iframe to show the aspx page in mvc like this

```
<iframe src="Aspx/MonitorProduct.aspx" width="1280" height="950" style="overflow:hidden;margin-top:0px;background-color:white;border:1px solid black"/>
```

I'm not sure is it what you want? But i hope this will help you.

Comment: Does it mean, MVC controller action call to view and view contain this iframew (iframe point to ASPX page). on code behind of ASPX page, write the all required code and ASPX page will cotian all require user control... is it ? will it work in same URL pattern as MVC route and ASPX/aspx.cs (traditionl) page will also work... right ?

Comment: Yes. "Aspx/MonitorProduct.aspx" can be changed to "@Url.Content("~/Aspx/Ascom.aspx")"
I'm not good in English i'm sorry if you don't understand me.\